# Burninate the [dba] and [database-administration] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The [database-administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-administration) and [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dba) tags are used on 1039 and 148 questions respectively.

They seem useless to me (on a site *called Database Administrators*) but I am curious as to how others feel.

**Should we [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642) (delete) these tags?**

This could be a first step to marking these tags as [intrinsic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218532) or [blacklisting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189), to prevent them being created again in future.

Thoughts? I have added a couple of Community Wiki answers to encourage voting on specific options. Please feel free to edit them to add additional reasoning, or add your own answer.

Comment: At first sight, since the site is about *administering databases*, those tags do not help to narrow the scope of a question which, to be on-topic, must be about *database administration* (that, naturally, implies the activities of a *DBA*, even if the person who is performing them does not hold such title or position) so they appear to be *kind of* redundant.

Comment: I do agree that dba is kind of useless. I could see administration in some fashion...unless we have a further refinement? Encourage the use of the area of administration? backup, restore, monitoring, performance, security, design (and that too could be logical, physical, hardware, etc.)

Comment: @ChrisAldrich The specific tags we already have seem to work quite well for 'area of administration'. I know what you mean though about 'database-administration' seeming like it *ought* to have some value in a vague sense. For the life of me, I can't think of good specific examples where more specific tags wouldn't be better, and 'database-administration' ends up adding no value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These tags are gone, and cannot be recreated; they're marked "intrinsic" so as to allow inbound migrations, but cannot be used on questions here.

Answer (score 24):

Yes [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dba) should be burninated because it...

- Isn't useful to connect experts in a topic area to questions they can answer
- Doesn't help describe the content of the question
- Doesn't add any meaningful information to the post
- Is ambiguous in that it could refer to the person or the role of a DBA
- Is simply the (abbreviated) name of the site

Answer (score 19):

Yes [database-administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-administration) should be burninated because it...

- Isn't useful to connect experts in a topic area to questions they can answer
- Doesn't help describe the content of the question
- Doesn't add any meaningful information to the post
- Is ambiguous in that it could refer to the person or the role of a DBA
- Is simply the name of the site